# R: Unusual output from write.table

Tags: r, output, multiple-columns, write.table

I am trying to export my simple data frame into a .txt file. My data frame BridgeGateHourlyDirection looks like:

[image: 6 columns]

I used the statement below

```
write.table(BridgeGateHourlyDirection, "X:/Maria/Trends/BridgeGateHourlyDOWDirection.txt", sep="\t",row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, eol="\n",na="NA",dec=".")
```

The output looks to be quite unusual and is not readable containing c(). It looks like this:
[image: text file output]

Has anyone experienced this before and found a solution?

```
sapply(BridgeGateHourlyDirection,class)
        Year        Month         Hour     DayClass        EBTot        WBTot 
   "integer"    "integer"    "integer"  "character" "data.frame" "data.frame"
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is sapply(BridgeGayeHourlyDirection, class)

Comment: How did you create the `BridgeGateHourlyDirection` object. Seems like you may have created an invalid data.frame at some point during your processing.

Comment: @MrFlick I created it using pivot_wider and then converted from a tibble into a data.frame. the data frame looks fine even when examining the whole data set

Comment: You can see from the `sapply` that you have `data.frames` inside your `data.frame` which doesn't bother tibbles but you cannot write out such a structure with `write.table`. It's hard to say how exactly that happened without some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)